# Is there a way to include submodules in GitHub download

Tags: github

I am using git submodules extensively in my projects, eg. when I use some library that is located in different repository, instead of copy pasting the code from library, I just add git submodule (reference to that repository itself).

The problem I am facing with this is that if you download the zip file using GitHub's download feature, the submodules are not part of a download. There are just empty folders and my program doesn't compile.

Is there any way to get GitHub to include submodules in the zip file?

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely.

For the git object database ("core git") a module link is just a special directory entry conaining only a SHA1. Only "external" tools like `git submodule` may interpret such entries and assign a valuable meaning to that SHA1. `git archive` in turn works directly with git object database. So my bet is that it's pretty hard to solve the task w/o a serious change of `git archive` internal logic.